# Как назначить векторному слою протокол и стратегию, а потом убрать их ?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Есть Vector слой тянущий данные с сервера сам (по стратегии Refresh). Нужно сделать его обычным Vector, без перезоздания. Пробовал strategies и protocol - не помогает, в том плане, что если я после этого начинаю добавлять в него объекты они не отображаются, даже если вызвать redraw().

```
layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
    "Вектор",
    {
        visibility: false,
        projection: map.displayProjection,
        strategies: [
            new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX({ resFactor: 1.1 }),
            new OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh({ force: true, interval: 20000 })
        ],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.Script({
            url: "http://site.ru/",
            filterToParams: function (filter, params) {
                if (filter.type === OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial.BBOX) {
                    params.bbox = filter.value.toArray();
                    if (filter.projection) {
                        params.bbox.push(filter.projection.getCode());
                    }
                }
                return params;
            }
        })
    }
);
```

Если пересоздаю протокол - все ок, он подхватывается и работает, но если ставлю стратегии null, то ничего не вижу. Если поставить protocol без изменения стратегии, то он выдает ошибку, что мол не может выполнить запрос или как-то так.

Как можно у векторного слоя убрать протокол и стратегию, сделав из него обычный векторный слой?

---

Второй день мучаюсь, и через несколько часов после того как задал вопрос почти решил его...

Нужно в нужном месте для очистки написать:

```
layer.strategies = [];
layer.protocol = null;
```

Либо сразу задать нужные. А для того чтобы быстро перерисовать одну фигуру нужно вызвать:

```
layer.drawFeature(layer.features[0]);
```

После применение новых strategies и protocol уже можно и так:

```
layer.redraw();
```

---

Осталось решить вопрос с отключением стратегии Refresh, иначе она все равно продолжает работать и по истечению интервала начинает выскакивать ошибка

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'read' of null
```

Подробности об ошибке:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'read' of null OpenLayers.js:1708
 OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed.OpenLayers.Class.load OpenLayers.js:1708
 OpenLayers.Events.OpenLayers.Class.triggerEvent OpenLayers.js:411
 OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.OpenLayers.Class.refresh OpenLayers.js:1536
 OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh.OpenLayers.Class.refresh OpenLayers.js:2348
  (anonymous function)
```